# "Unused global option(s)" error message

Tags: errors

I am trying to do my math homework, and my professor provided us with the code for the template.

I have done every homework in the past by copying and pasting it into a new document and then beginning to add my code, with no issues.

However, this time when I try to compile after I paste the template code I get an error that says "Unused global option(s)". How do I fix this?

Here is the template code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Do not alter the next line
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,onesided]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Fill in the appropriate information below
\newcommand{\DueDate}{10/31/19}           %change every time 

\newcommand{\Pin}{100}                    %change first time
\newcommand{\Name}{Engergizer Bunny}      %change first time
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%Do not alter this block of commands.
%If you're proficient at LaTeX, you may include additional packages,
%create macros (newcommands), etc.
%immediately below this block of commands, but make sure to
%NOT alter the header, margin, and comment settings here. 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,enumitem,color,comment,graphicx,environ}
\usepackage{wasysym}   %\smiley
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\textwidth}{500pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-68.4pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{650pt}  %700
\setlength{\voffset}{5pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-57.6pt} 
\setlength{\footskip}{32pt} 
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\lhead{Math 300}
\chead{}
\rhead{Pin: \Pin\\ \Name\\ {\tiny Due Date:} \DueDate} 
\lfoot{\footnotesize Last Modified: \today~at \currenttime} 
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\footnotesize Page \thepage\  of \pageref{LastPage}}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{23pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{exercise}[1]
           {\baselineskip 14 pt\vskip 10 pt\noindent\textbf{Exercise~#1.}}
           {\vsp{0}\hsp{100}\makebox[200pt]{\dotfill}\vsp{5}}
\newenvironment{lemma}[1]
           {\baselineskip 14 pt\vskip 10 pt\noindent\textbf{Lemma~#1.}}
           {\vsp{0}\hsp{100}\makebox[200pt]{\dotfill}\vsp{5}}
\newcommand{\soln}{\noindent\textsc{Solution}.  }          
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}      % how to make the Natural Numbers symbol. 
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb Q}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}  
\newcommand{\lp}{\left(}        % left parentheses
\newcommand{\rp}{\right)}       % right parentheses
\newcommand{\lc}{\left\{}       % left curly  
\newcommand{\rc}{\right\}}      % right curly 
\newcommand{\lb}{\left[}        % left bracket 
\newcommand{\rb}{\right]}       % right bracke
\newcommand{\lav}{\left\vert}   % left absolute value 
\newcommand{\rav}{\right\vert}  % right absolute value
\newcommand{\lv}{\left\langle\,}   % left vector sign  <
\newcommand{\rv}{\,\right\rangle}  % right vector sign >
\newcommand{\hsp}[1]{\hskip #1 pt}  
\newcommand{\vsp}[1]{\vskip #1 pt}
\newcommand{\tn}[1]{\textnormal{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{\textrm{\scriptsize $\left\langle\right.$\textrm{#1}$\left.\right\rangle$}} % comment to yourself
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  You can start adding your own newcommand (i.e., alias/macros)



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Do not alter this block.
\begin{document}
\baselineskip 22 pt % 22 pt is double spaced. 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Start your homework here










%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Do not alter anything below this line.
\vfill\eject
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE

Answer (score 9):

What you're getting is not an *error* message. Instead, it's just the following *warning* message:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [onesided].
```

You have two options (pun intended):

- Ignore the harmless warning.
- Drop the unused global option, i.e., change the instruction

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,reqno,onesided]{article}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,reqno]{article}
  ```

A final comment: The code of your instructor's template is quite inefficient and includes pointless instructions, such as `\vfill\eject` immediately before `\end{document}`. I wouldn't be surprised if you encounter various random-looking warning messages.

Comment: I see now, the same message appeared for the other homeworks, but it was below the compiled document so I did not notice it. I compiled just the template, so the document was blank and I could see the message which made me mistakenly think it wasn't working.

Comment: Aren't reqno also the default so can be dropped as well

Comment: @daleif - `reqno` is definitely the default -- and hence could definitely be dropped as well. (There was a reason for me pointing out that the template was rather inefficient...) The sole reason for why the OP doesn't encounter a second "Unused global option(s)" is that the `amsmath` package, which is loaded in the preamble, does process the option `reqno`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a third solution to @Mico -- you could replace the typo.  Actually, the correct class option would be `oneside` (not `onesided` as your professor said). `oneside` happens to be the default for the `article` and `report` classes.  As default options could safely be omitted, my advice could also safely reduced and traced back to Micos second solution.

But, as we are nowadays waisting lots of resources, including paper, I'd suggest, that you ignore the command of your professor and change the first line of your document into

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
```

**EDIT: tried to make the point of Layout more clear**

This would change the layout of your document to be twosided, i.e. prepare your document to print two logical pages on one sheet of paper, saving you (and our environment) roughly 50 % of the paper used.  Obviously, your printer has to support twosided printing as well.

Comment: The `twoside` option doesn't control the printing and amount of paper used, it just "flips" the margins and where margin notes go.

Comment: @StrongBad Therefore I wrote: "Obviously, your printer has to support twosided printing as well." :-) I edited my post and hope, it is more obvious now!